# Separating a Pandas column after the nth time a unique character appears

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am Trying to take a column in pandas with IDs like:

```
AB.156483.15645431.1561313513
CD.15615a.4651d15351.1512.1.21
```

I want to create a new column where everything up to but not including the 2nd period is returned.

```
AB.156483.15645431
CD.15615a.4651d15351
```

I've tried:

```
pattern = r'([^.]*,[^,]*)'
df['test'] = df.ID.str.extract(pattern, expand=False)
```

and receive string methods not callable

I've also tried splitting the cell into a list within the cell, then turning the list back into a string and reinstering the periods using list comprehension:

```
df['test'] = ' '.join([str(item+'.') for item in [df.ID.str.split('.').str[0:3]]])
```

Comment: Typo:  your `pattern` has commas where it should have periods.

Comment: You don't need regular expressions for that. Simple string methods will do it. Something like this: `'.'.join(s.split('.')[:3])`, where `s` is the content of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/5dpp6I/1):

```
df['test'] = df.ID.str.extract('^([^\.]+\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+)')
```

Or with split:

```
df['test'] = (df['ID'].str.split('.',3, expand=True)
                .iloc[:,:3].agg('.'.join, axis=1)
             )
```

Output:

```
                               ID                  test
0   AB.156483.15645431.1561313513    AB.156483.15645431
1  CD.15615a.4651d15351.1512.1.21  CD.15615a.4651d15351
```